# Laravel5 - Cache::remember forever

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5.3

Im trying to implement laravel's cache using the `remember` method. So how do I implement a forever with this? I tried passing `0` or `null` as minutes but it doesnt work.

I want the cache to be stored until its revoked my the code (i.e. forever).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found myself is to use `rememberForever`. Like this:

```
$my_data = Cache::rememberForever('key_123', function(){
//fetch from db and add to cache if not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Cache::forever('key','value')`

Comment: There is no `closure` in `forever`